# web-scrape basketball reference how to exclude the playoffs in April

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape [this page](https://www.basketballreference.com/leagues/NBA_2017_games-april.html).

I was able to scrape the results for October to March but I'm having problems for April because there is a `thead` for the playoffs ( `<tr class="thead" data-row="95"><th colspan="10">Playoffs</th></tr>`) and it is showing `ValueError: Unknown string format`. I would like the scraping to end or skip this specific row.

Here's my code :

```
data = [[td.getText() for td in data_rows[i].findAll(['th','td'])] for i in range(len(data_rows))]
```

Comment: what page are you scraping?

Comment: the site is https://www.basketballreference.com/leagues/NBA_2017_games-april.html. And the <tr class="thead" data-row="95"><th colspan="10">Playoffs</th></tr> is producing the error. I would like the scraping to end or skip this specific class. Thanks

Comment: I might have to be logged in or something, but [I can't view that](https://i.imgur.com/18AfuVg.png).

Comment: Oh, it's because you are going to sports-reference.com. it should be basketball-reference.com. Then go to seasons, click 2016-2017, then schedule & results. then finally go to April and there you will find my problem. Thanks

Comment: Huh, dont know how I got there, sorry about that.

Comment: @Benchpress could you edit your question and include the above info and link? As it is now is not clear; one needs to read the comments to fully understand the question.

Answer (score 2):

Loop through the `tr` elements and make sure you're not on the "Playoffs" `tr` before proceeding:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

webpage = urlopen("https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2017_games-april.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, 'html.parser')
data_rows = soup.find('table', {"id": "schedule"}).find_all('tr') # find all the 'tr' elements

for tr in data_rows: 
    if tr.text.strip() != "Playoffs": # check if were on the 'Playoffs' title tr
        data = [td.text for td in tr.find_all(["td", "th"])]
        print(data)
```

If you're using the latest version of BeautifulSoup, note that [`findAll()` is deprecated](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#method-names). Use `find_all()` instead. Similarly, use `.text` instead of `getText()`

Comment: @SeanBreckenridge, the methods `findAll()`, `getText()` etc are **not** deprecated. bs4 has backward compatibility with both bs2 and bs3. In the [bs4 source code](https://github.com/getanewsletter/BeautifulSoup4/blob/master/bs4/element.py) there are lines like this -> `findAll = find_all       # BS3`

Comment: @KeyurPotdar the [bs4 docs](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#porting-code-to-bs4) say: "Although BS4 is mostly backwards-compatible with BS3, most of its methods have been deprecated and given new names for PEP 8 compliance". I was under the impression it was just discouragement against using a function, not that it doesn't work. Is deprecated not the right word to use?

Comment: My bad. I was under an impression that *deprecated* means the function is obsolete (can't use anymore), but I read that it's a warning that in future it may become obsolete. Deprecated is the right word to use here.